# Get error list index out of range when print element from python list

Tags: python-3.x, list

This is my tes.py

```
def main () :
    idd = input("Enter ID : ")
    name = input("Enter Name : ")
    courses = [str]*3
    scores = [int]*3
    MyLib.inputCourses(courses)
    MyLib.inputScores(scores)
    MyLib.Display(idd,name,courses,scores)
main ()
```

This is my MyLib.py file

```
def inputCourses (cour) :
    for i in range(len(cour)) :
        cour[i] = str(input("Enter Courses : "))

def inputScores (scor) :
    for i in range(len(scor)) :
        scor[i] = int(input("Enter Scores Number : "))

def Display (idd,name,courses,scores) :
    print("ID :",idd)
    print("Name :", name)
    for i in scores :
        x = ""
        if i >= 86 and i <= 100 :
            x = "A"
        elif i >= 70 and i < 86 :
            x = "B"
        elif i >= 60 and i < 70 :
            x = "C"
        elif i >= 50 and i < 60 :
            x = "D"
        elif i >= 0 and i < 50 :
            x = "E"
        else :
            print("Invalid Score")
        if x :
            print("Courses",courses[i],"Score Number",i,"Letter Grades", x)
```

When I tried to run this program, it will error `list index out of range`, after I tried some experiment, `courses[i]` make it error.

```
# Input
Enter ID : 11124521
Enter Name : Jakky
Enter Courses : Math
Enter Courses : Physics
Enter Courses : Chemistry
Enter Scores : 88
Enter Scores : 75
Enter Scores : 52
# Output that I want to get
Courses Math Score Number 88 Letter Grades A
Courses Physics Score Number 75 Letter Grades B
Courses Chemistry Score Number 52 Letter Grades D
```

I dont know what should I add for my code, I tried to search it in google but I dont get what I want to know

Comment: Welcome to SO! `for i in lst` means "assign `i` to the value of each item in `lst`. So if `lst` is `[1000, 12301]` and you go `lst[i]` when `i` is `1000`, you'll get an index error. You probably want `for index, score in enumerate(scores):`. Don't name a variable `i` if it's anything other than an index.

Comment: @ggorlen Umm, I understand your explaination about `for i in lst`, but for this code `for index, score in enumerate(Score)` I dont know what to do with this, I never use this code before, sorry I am still a beginner

Comment: `enumerate(lst)` generates pairs of index and the list element itself. Where you need the index in the loop block, use the index. Where you need the number in the loop block, use the number. https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/. The way you're doing it, you have no way to access the index at the same time as the number. If `enumerate` makes no sense, you can use `for i in range(len(scores))` to get the index, then use `scores[i]` to get the element.

Comment: @ggorlen I see, for now maybe I will use `for in in range(len(...)`, thanks for your explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your function def Display() in the file MyLibs.py, your loop is iterating the VALUES in the list scores, so according to your inputs, i will be 88, 75, 52 - as these are your score inputs. You have only 3 items in your list - Courses. So Courses[88] is invalid, hence your error

One simple fix would be to add a new variable before the for loop, say y=0
and then after the print statement under if x: , you can add y+=1. You then change courses[i] to courses[y] so that you won't get index error

```
def Display (idd,name,courses,scores) :
print("ID :",idd)
print("Name :", name)
print(courses)
y=0
for i in scores :
    x = ""
    if i >= 86 and i <= 100 :
        x = "A"
    elif i >= 70 and i < 86 :
        x = "B"
    elif i >= 60 and i < 70 :
        x = "C"
    elif i >= 50 and i < 60 :
        x = "D"
    elif i >= 0 and i < 50 :
        x = "E"
    else :
        print("Invalid Score")
    if x :
        print("Courses",courses[y],"Score Number",i,"Letter Grades", x)
        y+=1
```